Different behaviour when run the same code on Leetcode and VScode
Here's a code for the program using recursion,
"Given an integer n, return true if it is a power of three. Otherwise, return false."
class Solution:
    def isPowerOfThree(self, n: int) -> bool:

        if(n>0):
            if(n == 1 or n == 3): return True
            elif(n%3 != 0): return False
            else: self.isPowerOfThree(n/3)

        else: return False

This code when run in vs code passes all the test cases, while when run in Leetcode fails the test case of "27".
How is this possible? or does Leetcode compiler behave differently?

you can use integer division // instead of floating-point division /

There is the missing return statement
else:
    return self.isPowerOfThree(n // 3)

without this it can be return as None , it can lead to recursive calls not returning the boolean value.

class Solution:
def isPowerOfThree(self, n: int) -> bool:

    if(n>0):
        if(n == 1 or n == 3): return True
        elif(n%3 != 0): return False
        else: return self.isPowerOfThree(n/3)

    else: return False

You should always return values in the else block. The code can successfully run on vscode because it will auto-adjust some small mistakes, but Leetcode don't do that.

Thanks for responding! Didn't know that about VS code, glad to learn something new
